# UIActionSheet Customization

Tags: iphone

[image]

Can we change the order in which the destructive button and Other buttons appear in an UIActionSheet. By default the destructive button (red colored) appears above other buttons, in my app I would like the other buttons to appear above the destructive button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make any button in the UIActionSheet as destruction button by using the UIActionSheet property destructiveButtonIndex like,

```
actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 6):

No Problem.

Just alloc and init a new UIActionSheet instance and add the buttons in your order (one after another) using `–addButtonWithTitle:`. This method returns you the index at which the button has been added to. You can then set the Index of the destructive button via `-setDestructiveButtonIndex:`.