# How to add a custom control to ActionSheet with default buttons?

Tags: iphone

I want to customise a `UIActionSheet` slightly; Just add a custom UIButton/UIImageView above the existing 2 buttons like in this previous post but with a custom button/image instead of text above the default buttons. I tried adding a simple `UILabel` to see if it works as in this post: [UIActionSheet Customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734566/uiactionsheet-customization).

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                     initWithTitle: @""
                          delegate: self    
                 cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",@"cancel button")
            destructiveButtonTitle: nil
                 otherButtonTitles: @"Send",nil];

actionSheet.tag = kCallActionSheetTag;

UILabel *btn = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
                         CGRectMake(18, 10, 140, 50)];
accountLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
accountLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
accountLabel.text = @"Account";
accountLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
accountLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[actionSheet addSubview:accountLabel];
[accountLabel release];
[actionSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.view];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 260)];
[actionSheet release];
```

If I use the code above, the two buttons are displaced vertically upwards and `UILabel` overlaps the top button. They seem to be locked to the top of the actionsheet. I would rather not add my own buttons and position them. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is my suggestion,

My experience is from UIAlertView, I have not tested.

It is supposed to set top message huge to offset button y-offset.

then add your UILabel