# How do I change the button color in a UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a UIAlertView with several buttons. I want to make a certain button red. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then try UIActionSheet instead of UIAlertView

Comment: I switched to a UIActionSheet. Can I change the color of a actionsheet button?

Comment: reference says:
destructiveButtonTitle
The title of the destructive button. This button is added to the action sheet automatically and assigned an appropriate index, which is available from the destructiveButtonIndex property. This button is displayed in **red** to indicate that it represents a destructive behavior. Specify nil if you do not want a destructive button.

Comment: I have my other buttons coded. How do I code the destructuve button?

Comment: `UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Button" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive Button" otherButtonTitles:@"Other Button 1", @"Other Button 2", nil];`

Comment: Thanks! What I would like to do is name the destructiveButtonTitle to Restart(No Problem). My next step is to have the Destruct button next to last. How would I go about coding the destruct button? Do I use the button index ==?

Comment: chk this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734566/uiactionsheet-customization

Comment: Where would I put this line of code? actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex = 1;

Comment: Works great...simple solution

Answer (score 1):

Though the original question was how to change UIAlertView button colour, it was then changed to UIActionSheet so jus in case if someone will be looking for changing UIActionSheet buttons colours the following UIActionSheet delegate method can be used:

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
     for (UIView *aView in actionSheet.subviews) {
        UIButton *aButton = (UIButton *)aView;
        [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot subclass `UIAlertView`. Please take a look at this link from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Comment: You sure can, at least in iOS7 and iOS8. In Swift, that would look something like this:

`class MyAlertView: UIAlertView {
    
    init(customParams: .....) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

   setup() {
      // Setup buttons, delegates...whatever you want
   }

   // More custom logic...
}`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately UIAlerView has no method to change the color of buttons. 
If you want a different looking UIAlertView you have to design it yourself an present it as a modal view.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think you can change it. Maybe only by using categories to overwrite, which is definitely not encouraged by apple. However, creating a custom uialertview is quite easy.